Why can't infinitesimal canonical transformations be used to represent infinitesimal boosts?
Consider the following differential form:
\begin{equation}
    \textbf{d}F=Q\textbf{d}P+p\textbf{d}q+(K-H)\textbf{d}t
\end{equation}
The generating function for the canonical transformation is given by:
\begin{equation}
    F=q_iP_i+\epsilon G
\end{equation}
Thus, the transformed phase space coordinates $(Q,P)$ obtained through the canonical transformation are:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        Q_i&=q_i+\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial P_i}
        \\
        p_i&=P_i+\epsilon \frac{\partial G}{\partial q_i}
        \\
        K&=H+\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In the case of a small velocity boost, the four-dimensional momentum transformation can be written as:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        K&=H-\epsilon p_1
        \\
        P_1&=p_1-\epsilon H
        \\
        Q_1&=q_1-\epsilon t
    \end{aligned}
    \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{while} \,\,\,v_{boost}=\epsilon
\end{equation}
From this, we can deduce the partial derivatives of $G$ with respect to the variables as:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial G}{\partial P_1}=-t,\frac{\partial G}{\partial q_1}=H,\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=-p_1
\end{equation}
My question is:
It's obvious that $$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P_1\partial q_1}$$ is unconfirmed.
But theoretical mechanics should be compatible with relativity. Why isn't such a transformation allowed?

There is a dimensionality problem with your $K$ and $P_1$.  If $\epsilon$ has dimensions of velocity, then $\epsilon p_1$ has dimensions of energy but $\epsilon H$ does not have dimensions of momentum.

@ZeroTheHero. well, that's a point I would like to clarify is that I used natural units:c=1

and the main problem is: $\frac{\partial G}{\partial P_1}=-t$ result in ,$\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial P_1\partial q_1}=0$,on the other hand,$\frac{\partial G}{\partial q_1}=H$ result in ,$\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial P_1\partial q_1}=P_1/H$

Something's conceptually wrong with your setup (and I don't have time to track it down).  In the limit where $\epsilon\to 0$, your $G$ should go to $H$ so it makes no sense to have $\partial G/\partial q_1=H$.   For canonical transformations $t$ is a "parameter" so it's not clear why a small boost transformation can be conceived as a canonical transformation but again I don't have time to research this further.
